ngnix reverse proxy settings - port not available
I use ngix as reverse proxy. Is there a way to show a specifc html page, if the port (e.g. 1111) is not available (e.g. during restart of the application):
location /app/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1111/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
} 


The port 1111 is for your internal application and it is the port you specify.

Yes, it is the internal port. But if the application is not running I want to show a html page

Currently I get only the message: Bad Gateway - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.

https://serverfault.com/questions/537634/nginx-serving-alternate-location-on-404 see if it helps.

error_page 502 = https://www.xyz.de/xyz.html; was the trick - thanks a lot
